# Orchard custom form style

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, orchardcms

I am new to Orchard and I have just created a new custom form "Contact us". However I am looking to style this form but I am unsure where to obtain identifiers for each textbox. Using the shape tracer, I created the EditorTemplate-ContactusForm.cshtml in my views, where i have three text boxes(which should be):

Name:
text box

Email:
text box

Query:
text box

I'am just trying to find the right code to bind the text box to the correct model. That can allow me to style it using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, that designer tools are only going to help with shapes. The MVC textbox that i was using wasn't the correct method. So instead, I located the correct alternate for both the shape and used the HTML section, copied it and added it to the view.

Answer (score 0):

you are going in right direction now that you have created template add CSS file styles folder and reference it with`Style.Include("XYZ.css")` User source code of page to see on which id or class should you apply your stylings

Comment: its not really the styling have problems with but identifying the actual html form code for instance : @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailAddress), this is the current call for the text box but it doesn't work, is there an alternative or a set way to obtain them